# Android appcompt library 23.1.1: CollapsingToolbarLayout not collapsing while scrolling

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-support-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

This code works perfect if I use "**com.android.support:design:23.0.1**" but If I update gradel with the new version "**com.android.support:design:23.1.1**" is like everything is frozen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            >
            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="192dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/header"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        tools:text="Your Name"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/period"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        tools:text="Period"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="18sp"    
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/year"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        tools:text="2015"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="18sp"    
                        />
                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Problems**

- I can't collapse
- I can't scroll the RecyclerView

If I comment " **CollapsingToolbarLayout** " the RecyclerView scroll without problem

Comment: Update all support library like appcompat to same version.

Answer (score 0):

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
```

Use this in CollapsingToolbarLayout and see if its working.